Decorator in python-flask is giving "AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function"
I am writing a flask endpoint with decorator added for JWT decoding, but it keeps giving me the error
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function

I am trying to decode the JWT token (using the decorator) then passing the payload from the wrapper to the decorated function to display/return as response.
My snippet is:
def get_config(section):
    with open('./config/configurations.yml',"r") as file:
        config = yaml.safe_load(file)
    return config[section]

def decode_jwt_token(token, secret_key, algo):
    try:
        decoded_payload = jwt.decode(token,secret_key,algorithms=[algo])
        return decoded_payload
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        print("Token has expired")
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        print("Invalid Token")

def decodeJWT(func):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        config = get_config("jwt")
        auth_header = request.headers.get("Authorization")
        if auth_header and auth_header.startswith('Bearer'):
            token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
            payload = decode_jwt_token(token, config["secret"], config["jwt_algorithm"])
            return func(payload=payload)
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid Token'}), 401
    return wrapper

@app.route("/test",methods=["GET"])
@decodeJWT
def test(**kwargs):
    payload = kwargs.get("payload",None)
    if payload is None:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid'}), 401
    return jsonify({'message': 'This is a secure message', 'data': payload}), 200

The full error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\al90935\Documents\flask_rest_api\app.py", line 45, in <module>
    def test(**kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\al90935\Documents\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\sansio\scaffold.py", line 362, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\Users\al90935\Documents\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\sansio\scaffold.py", line 47, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\al90935\Documents\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\sansio\app.py", line 657, in add_url_rule
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper

Where am I going wrong? ..is it somewhere while passing the argument "payload" ?

I solved the issue by renaming the wrapper function to some other name, since the name wrapper was already being used in one more decorator function.
I renamed the wrapper from:
def decodeJWT(func):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):

to
def decodeJWT(func):
    def wrapper_decoder(**kwargs):

because i already had one more decorator that was defined as (with the name wrapper):
def secure_endpoint(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

and now its working fine.
